# Identity Aware Proxy (IAP) for a URL - Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine-python, google-iap

We have two projects -

Project 1 - Google App engine standard python 2.7.
Project 2 - Google Appp engine standard python 3.3

Project 1 application is secured using Firebase user authentication.
We have a need to access a particular function (URL) of Project 1 accessing from Project 2. The call from Project 2 will be done by the server (not user). We need this to be secure.

Can we enable just this function (URL) in Project 1 with IAP? And use the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto) to authenticate?

It the above is not a solution, what are our options?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the link you provide exposes proper solutions. Although, I believe the best one is to use a Service Account for Project 2 that allows access to Project 1 resource (Use the proper Cloud Function role).

Include the Service Account credentials in Project 2 and use the proper library to call the service using the Service account credentials. Learn how to create a Service account credential [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys)

Comment: How do we secure Project1? Right now it is open to any traffic. Project 1 application access is authenticated by Firesbase user. If we keep the firebase authentication for this function in Project 1 how do we use service account to access it?

Comment: You have to secure the Cloud function of project 1. If the service you are trying to access is in the backend of AppEngine you cant secure without securing the hole thing. AppEngine Permissions are homogenous. 

Depending on the deploy process you follow this may change a little. Once you do that, only authenticated requests can invoke the resource.

Comment: You can manually add authentication to the backend handlers of your AppEngine service, but this might be more complicated than separating your service from AppEngine into a cloud function.

Comment: This is the problem we are facing. We don't want to IAP the whole application (Project 1). Because this is open in the internet and authentication is based on firebase. We need only one handler that needs to be accessed securely by Project 2's server. So the recommendation is to create a Cloud function in Project 1 and make that accessible to Project 2?